# Detecting faces in video file. Error in using data type

Tags: matlab, viola-jones

I have the following question.
I'm working with matlab 2016.
I want to detect faces in a video file, using the Viola-Jones algorithm.
When I try to enter a video file in the `step` statement, I get the following error:

```
Error using
   vision.CascadeObjectDetector/validateInputsImpl
   (line 330)
   Expected input number 2 to be
   one of these types:

   uint8, uint16, double, single,int16

   Instead its type was
   vision.VideoFileReader.

   Error in VJ1_video (line 12)
   bboxes = step(faceDetector, videoFReader);
```

I understand that somehow the type of VideoFileReader should be converted to one of the types: uint8, uint16, double, single, int16.
But I do not understand how this can be done. Tell me please. 
Here is my program code:

```
clear all;
%Load the video using a video reader object
  videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('D:\465.avi');
%Create a detector object.
  faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;
%Detect faces.
  bboxes = step(faceDetector, videoFReader);
%Annotate detected faces
  IFaces = insertObjectAnnotation(videoFReader, 'rectangle', bboxes, 'Лицо');
%Create a video player object to play the video file.
  videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;

%Use a while loop to read and play the video frames.
  while ~isDone(videoFReader)
    videoFrame = videoFReader();
    videoPlayer(videoFrame);
  end
%Release the objects.
  release(videoPlayer);
  release(videoFReader);
```

Answer (score 0):

The CascadeObjectDetector works on single frames (images), not on a sequence of frames (video). Accordingly input of the [`step`](https://de.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/vision.cascadeobjectdetector.step.html) function is, as you already suggested, an image. Change your code so that the face detection happens while you iterate over the frames.

An (untested) suggestion:

```
    %Load the video using a video reader object
      videoFReader = vision.VideoFileReader('D:\465.avi');
    %Create a video player object to play the video file.
      videoPlayer = vision.VideoPlayer;
    %Create a detector object.
      faceDetector = vision.CascadeObjectDetector;

    %Use a while loop to read and play the video frames.
      while ~isDone(videoFReader)
        videoFrame = videoFReader();
        %Detect faces.
        bboxes = step(faceDetector, videoFReader);
        %Annotate detected faces
        IFaces = insertObjectAnnotation(videoFReader, 'rectangle', bboxes, 'Лицо');
        %Show annotated frames IFaces (instead of videoFrame)
        videoPlayer(IFaces);
      end

    %Release the objects.
      release(videoPlayer);
      release(videoFReader);
```